# Functional approach to apply mapped args to a function's default/named params

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm provided a library with a builder function using default/named params. Something like

```
def builder = new {
    def apply(
      a:Int = 0,
      b:Int = 0,
      c:Int = 0):String = {
       "a="+a+", b="+b+", c="+c
      }
}
```

I need to consume a Mapped Collection of parameters (http query params) and call the builder properly. I can brute force it with repetitive code but there must be a better "functional" way to do this. Below is my rather poor attempt. As you can see it overrides the builder's default params. Please show me the light!

```
val inParams = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3) //3 params passed in

builder(
  in.get("a").getOrElse(0),
  in.get("b").getOrElse(0),
  in.get("c").getOrElse(0)
)

val inParams = Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 3) //2 params, out of sequence
builder(
  in.get("a").getOrElse(0),
  in.get("b").getOrElse(0),
  in.get("c").getOrElse(0)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for responses. They are definitely an improvement over the original code. However, is there a way to preserve the default parameter of the builder's apply function when no map k/v is present?

Comment: Do you mean that the default values could be other than 0, and different for different parameters?

Comment: The default, as defined in the builder, must be used if a parameter is not given when the function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` has a `getOrElse` method.

```
val in = Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 3) //2 params, out of sequence
builder(
  in.getOrElse("a", 0),
  in.getOrElse("b", 0),
  in.getOrElse("c", 0)
)
```

Or you can also do:

```
val in = Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 3).withDefaultValue(0)
builder(in("a"), in("b"), in("c"))
```

Comment: Good simplification. But the default value, as defined in the "builder", must be used if a parameter is not given when the function is called. Any thoughts on how to approach this issue?

Comment: @eptx: I guess you want to do [something like this](https://gist.github.com/1214994) (Python code). Unfortunately this kind of thing is not possible in Scala. With Java reflection libraries, you cannot obtain the names and default values of parameters of Scala methods. And Scala does not have a reflection library of its own (yet).

Comment: Slick Python example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with — not great, I know; improvements are welcome.

```
val Seq(a, b, c) = Seq("a", "b", "c").map(p => inParams.getOrElse(p, 0))
builder(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is only a small improvement...

```
def mapping[A](s:String, m:Map[String,A], d:A):Seq[A] = 
  s.map(k => m.getOrElse(k.toString,d))

val in = Map("a" -> 1, "c" -> 3)
val Seq(a,b,c) = mapping("abc", in, 0)
builder(a,b,c)
```